# Displaying iBeacon-based locations on a floor image

Tags: ios, image, core-location, ibeacon, indoor-positioning-system

I've deployed some `iBeacon` devices in several rooms of a building's floor for testing, and I'd like to show the user's current indoor location on a custom image of the floor to let her know in which room she is.

I've been already reading about monitoring `iBeacon` regions, but I do not know how to deal with the following tasks:

1. To create an image of the floor I could use in the app
2. To map user's locations on the floor image: how could I draw positions on my custom floor image, and make them fit the rooms in the image? I guess I firstly should create a database of measures to relate signal strenghts with rooms... right? And which kind of controls should I use, simply an `UIImageView` for my custom floor image and another for the position? Any tutorial of how to face this process?

I'd appreciate some guidence or a starting point, thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

1. The answer is simple: Use a drawing application to draw the room or building plan.
2. There are some approaches to find out the position of the device by using beacons: Trilateration or NonLinear Regression algorithms. Please read my answer to the indoor positioning [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29091720/indoor-navigation-using-i-beacon-accuracy-is-changing-rapidly/29378983#29378983).

To map your image room plan to the real device position you need to link the display points (pixels) to meters. For example x: 200 points <-> 1m, y: 400 points <-> 1m

In your app you could than specify the x/y position of each ibeacon in meter. With the knowledge about the room plan scale above and the position of the beacons you can navigate the user device.

To display the device position on the room plan you could use a SpriteKit. [Here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/42699/spritekit-tutorial-for-beginners) is a relevant tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use Photoshop or some other drawing application. Alternatively, you could ask the city for blueprints of the building and scan them.
2. You cannot currently track user location accurately. You can make guesses based on signal strength detected from beacons within proximity of your device, but you will get no directionality and no distance measurements. All current "distance" measurements are approximations based on signal strength and can suffer from interference or signal boosting.

Comment: 2 ) If you have a lot of beacons, you can triangulate a user location, though it won't be ultra-precise (unless you put a lot of beacons), it will allows you to see in which room the user is.

Comment: Adding more beacons to the system simply adds more interference (and cost); it does not add accuracy. At this moment in time, the only measurement you get from a beacon is its signal strength.

Comment: Thanks. About 2, what I meant is: how could I draw positions on my custom floor image, and make them fit the rooms in the image? I guess I firstly should create a database of measures to relate signal strenghts with rooms... right? And how could I represent this? Any tutorial of how to face this process?

Comment: My point was, if you have 3 beacons within reach, you can detect approximatively where the user is. For sure, this will not be precise, but it will be better than the result you will have with only 1 beacon. Let's hope that Apple Maps Connect will give us more too for efficient indoor location !

Comment: Your database will relate the UUID+Major+Minor reported by the beacon to a map coordinate. You will need to record these relations manually into your database. When your app detects a beacon, you will be provided this lookup information and you can attempt to position the user.